# le poste = jail ?

Tags: sens, régionalismes

I have just heard a mother talking about her problematic young son in S1E02 of the TV series "Unité 42", produced in Belgium:

- Je passais mon temps à le chercher au poste.

If I understood right, "poste" means "jail" here. In the [Word Reference dictionary](https://www.wordreference.com/fren/poste), the only definition of "poste" as "jail" is in the expression "embarquer qqn au poste". Is the usage of "poste" as "jail" in the sentence above (chercher qqn au poste) a Belgium regionalism or is it also used in other French-speaking countries?

Comment: In means "poste de police", which is the police station. A lot of people are taken there to do what we call a "garde à vue", a short detention that lasts between 24 hours and a few days.

Comment: Please, don't write comments to provide an answer. Use comments to ask for more information or clarify a question or answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Despite her son may have been put behind bars, "poste" is not exactly a "jail": it is an abbreviation for "poste de police" ("police station") like "precinct" may be an abbreviation for "precinct station".

"Poste" is widely used in France too.